# Make the legend disappear in Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I am using Highcharts and I am trying to make the legend to disappear and appear using a button, to save some screen real-estate.

I tried everything I could think of and all I managed to do is to make the SVG of the legend to hide and show using `chart.legend.[group, nav, container].hide()` but the white space which the legend takes never goes away. I even tried deleting the legend DOM element but the chart wouldn't resize (even calls to `chart.reflow()` don't help.

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/zbzzn/q83h5g4z/1/

Is there any way to make the legend disappear and reflow the chart so that the legend white space goes away?

Answer (score 1):

Here's my sketch for a toggle method that sits directly on the Legend prototype. It avoids modifying the container width and height.

```
Highcharts.Legend.prototype.toggle = function () {
    if (this.display) {
        this.group.hide();
    } else {
        this.group.show();
    }
    this.display = !this.display;
    this.chart.isDirtyBox = true;
    this.chart.redraw();
};
```

Live demo at http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/3Bh7b/76/

Comment: Thanks for the solution, it still has the issue of the nav group: http://jsfiddle.net/3Bh7b/79/

Comment: And I forgot to mention that sometimes I have series added in runtime so even if I hide that nav group it re-appears if you add another series.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do a hack around it that works:

http://jsfiddle.net/q83h5g4z/4/

I really hope there is another way to do it without the hack.

```
    if (!isVisible) {
        originalLegendHeight = legend.legendHeight;
        legend.options.maxHeight = -1; //0 doesn't work :( because someone did "if (maxHeight)" instead of "if (maxHeight === null)" 
        $('#container').height($('#container').height()-legend.legendHeight); 
        chart.redraw();
        chart.reflow();
    } else {
        legend.options.maxHeight = null;
        $('#container').height($('#container').height()+originalLegendHeight);
        chart.redraw();
        chart.reflow();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

See this solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/3Bh7b/73/

```
var legend = chart.legend; 

            if(legend.display) {
                legend.group.hide();
                legend.display = false;
            } else {

                legend.group.show();
                legend.display = true;
            }
```

Comment: I started my tests from this solution (see the question description) but it didn't work because it doesn't resize the chart and it doesn't hide the nav group when it appears.

Comment: Indeed you are right, I dont see this requirements.

Comment: Do you have another solution other than the one in my answer? Can I put this feature as an enhancement request on the HighCharts GitHub?

Comment: We gather all suggestions in our [uservoice](http://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-general) service, so you can post it there. See next example which I prepared: http://jsfiddle.net/3Bh7b/74/

Comment: Thank you for the information. In this example the same problem still exists. The "highcharts-legend" element still takes 75px.

Comment: Looks like it was already requested - http://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-general/suggestions/2698586-toggle-legend-box

Answer (score 0):

The final solution I reached is (where legendVisible determines the visibility of the legend) :

```
            var legendElement = $(chart.container).find('.highcharts-legend');
            if (legendElement.length > 0) {
                if (chart.legend.options.enabled && legendVisible) {
                    legendElement.show();
                    chart.legend.options.maxHeight = chart.legend.options.originalMaxHeight || null;
                    chart.reflow();
                } else {
                    legendElement.hide();
                    chart.legend.options.originalMaxHeight = chart.legend.options.maxHeight;
                    chart.legend.options.maxHeight = -1;
                    chart.reflow();
                }
            }
```